# Can temperature difference in a conductor induce charge in it?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, temperature

Assume a metallic rod which is heated on its right end to maintain a constant temperature gradient in the rod.
 Now if we take any crossection in the rod,the right side part of the cross section has more temperature than leftward part so the velocity of electrons in the right part is high compared to electrons in left part.So more electrons from rightside cross the cross section than leftward electrons.This results in charge development across the ends of rod.

Comment: The short answer is that you are right. However the wording a bit misleading, it isn't that you charge the rod. It is that you displace the charges in such a way that the charge distribution isn't homogeneous anymore across the rod. But you are absolutely right, this is the Seebeck effect in an open circuit. There is a widespread misconception that the Seebeck effect requires 2 materials to manifest itself, but this is wrong.Note that this has nothing to do with the Thomson effect, which requires both a current and a temperature gradient to manifest itself, while here you have an open circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Thermoelectric effects, the Seebeck potential.

But in metals it is very small, because temperature does not have much effect on the kinetic energy of the electron gas.

It is much larger in doped semiconductors, where the electrons can be treated as a classical Drude gas.

Comment: In a homogenoeus metal this is called the Thomson effect see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Thomson_effect (The Seebeck/Peltier effect refers to what happens at the junction of two different metals)

Comment: @hyportnex Pieter is correct. The Seebeck effect can take place across a single material as the asker describes, it is an open circuit. However if you want to measure that voltage with a voltmeter, you must use a different material else the reading will be 0. But the effect is there even in a single material. Also, regarding the Thomson effect (which is a generation or absorption of heat, not a voltage), it occurs only when both a current and a temperature gradient are present. So, in an open circuit as described, there is no Thomson effect.